# Why can't I start a debug session on Eclipse using Xdebug?

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I've been debugging in Eclipse with Xdebug without any problems, but for some reason since this morning, when I try to start a debug session, I get an error like this from Eclipse:

"The file 'http://localhost/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=ECLIPSE_DBGKEY=13288911493954' could not be found.

In my phpinfo file, I can see that Xdebug is working.

I'm using Elipse 3.7.1, Xdebug 2.1.3.

This is the Xdebug config in my php.ini file:
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"

```
[XDebug] 
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you receive is because Eclipse is trying to *stop* a debugging session. It's a wrong URL as well, as it should really say "http://localhost/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=1". Why it wants to stop, I can't tell you, but the ?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=1 gets captured by Xdebug and makes the request not proceed.
To find out, you can perhaps use the xdebug.remote_log setting (http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) to create a log file on what Eclipse is trying to get Xdebug to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I posted the message it displays when I hit the stop button. 

When I try to start a debugging the message is the following: 
The file 'http://eu.localhost/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGPKEY=13300126438901' could not be found.

I created xdebug.log in the tmp folder and added the following line to my php.ini

xdebug.remote_log = "./../tmp/xdebug.log"

I restarted the services, and tried again, but when I open the xdebug.log file, I find it blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's crazy... when I hit the link in my previous comment, a debugging session actually starts... But it doesn't when I try from Eclipse... I guess I'm just going to have to bookmark this post and hit that link every time I want to start a debugging session.